# Cannot pip install with python 2,7 virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, pyenv

I am trying to use the following `OCR` project that is found [here on github](https://github.com/tmbarchive/ocropy). I am using python 3 virtual environment. I am on Windows. I installed successfully `requirements.txt` using `Python 3.6.7`, however when I am attempting to do `python install setup.py` I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: you must install and use OCRopus with Python version 2.7 or later, but not Python 3.x
```

Having this said, I reverted back and tried to use `Python 2.7` with the `virtual environment` using `pyenv-win` [link](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). When I try to install `requirements.txt` with the virtual env of `python 2.7` I get the following error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:380: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning,
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/numpy/
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/numpy/
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/numpy/
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/numpy/
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
C:\Users\User\venv\ocropus\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:139: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
(ocropus)
```

Does that mean I cannot install these python packages at all using python 2.7 ? I have to use this repository for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, `ocropy needs Python 2.7 but numpy and scipy newest versions dropped Python 2.7 support.` However, you can still use them but the problem is that our developer folks will stop supporting bug fixes.

My problem was mainly the global version of Python I have on my system (windows) is `3.6.7` while ocropus requires `2.7`. I downloaded a broken executable for `Python 2.7` that did not have the **Scripts** folder installed, thus **pip** ended up not working at all.

Followed [this](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation) tutorial that shows how to install another version of python (2.7) and the problem was solved when I downloaded the following [executable](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)

In order to use the`virtualenv` properly with python `2.7` use the following command

```
# dont forget to add python.exe 
virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe venv/ocropus
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

Read your error again, and you will see this at the 2nd line of your error:

```
This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate,
```

These all errors are SSL warnings, and as stated in error, python is telling you to upgrade python to python 3, but as the OCR project uses python version 2, so you have two solutions:

1. Either, Manually download the requirements and install them
2. Or, leave OCR project because python 2 is old now, no longer supported

I hope i have answered your question

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I agrepython 2 is old, but I am forced to use this project. I fixed the issue and will reply in a separate answer